# How Do I Return Cell Reference from a String Search Using VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel

How do I extract a list of cell references from a string search found under the 1st column using VBA? For example, from the image attached below, how do I return a list of cell references of the string "Apple" from the 1st row? Preferably the list of the cell references should be listed under the 2nd column.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5pHQ.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `Find()` for this.  Try it out then post back (with code!) if you run into a specific problem

Comment: try using in Instr() function to string search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Option Compare Text 'to remove case sensitivity

Sub test()
    Dim S1$, S2$, Fruits As Range, x As Range
    Set Fruits = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each x In Fruits
        If x.Value2 = "Apple" Then
            S1 = S1 & " " & x.Address(0, 0)
        ElseIf x.Value2 = "Kiwi" Then
            S2 = S2 & " " & x.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next
    S1 = Mid(S1, 2, Len(S1)): S2 = Mid(S2, 2, Len(S2))
    Range([B2], Cells(UBound(Split(S1)) + 2, "B")) = Application.Transpose(Split(S1))
    Range([C2], Cells(UBound(Split(S2)) + 2, "C")) = Application.Transpose(Split(S2))
End Sub
```

test:

[image]